# Creat List From CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in PHP. I am working for make bulk message script for twillio. Its require number list like below

```
$subscribers = [
   json_encode(['binding_type' => "sms", 'address' => "+910000000000"]),
   json_encode(['binding_type' => "sms", 'address' => "+910000000000"])
];
```

I have data in csv file like below image

[image]

I am able to read the data from it like below

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

When I do

```
print_r($csv);
```

its showing data like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 910000000000) [1] => Array ( [0] => 910000000000) )
```

I am not getting idea how I can create list like below for use with twillio

```
$subscribers = [
   json_encode(['binding_type' => "sms", 'address' => "+910000000000"]),
   json_encode(['binding_type' => "sms", 'address' => "+910000000000"])
];
```

Let me know if anyone here can help me for do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
    

    $subscribers = array();

    foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
        $item = array();
        $item['binding_type'] = "sms";
        $item['address'] =  "+".$value[0];

        array_push($subscribers, json_encode($item));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Same thing as I would have suggested, but have you notices that `$csv` has got an nested array? Just change `foreach ($csv as $key => $value)` to `foreach ($csv[0] as $key => $value)` and your code would work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, My code is working fine. tested. Not requires to change anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, you're right. My mistake. I was only looking at the output of `print_r($csv);` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Your suggestion also correct. we need change `$value[0];` to `$value;` in your suggestion. Thanks